# Two users with same name but different passwords

Tags: security, users

Is it possible to create two users with the same name, and let LightDM choose between them at login if one of the passwords is given?

For example, to anyone opening my computer, it would seem like there is only one user.
If he would enter the right password, he would login to the "real" user, if he enters another pre-defined password he would login to the "dummy" account, and any other password would result in an error.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain your use case just a bit more? Just out of interest...

Comment: @Private:
Well, I don't really need it. I've read about something similar to this (on a smartphone, though) in a fictional book. I just wanted to know if it can be accomplished on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150487/what-happens-under-the-covers-to-log-me-in-and-start-up-the-unity-graphics-user) provides some detail about the login sequence.

Authentication is handled by [PAM](https://fedorahosted.org/linux-pam/) (pluggable authentication modules). A brief search doesn't turn up any existing implementation of this idea (or at least, not one that is part of the standard Ubuntu set-up - I wouldn't be surprised if someone, somewhere had done it).

[This message](http://www.redhat.com/archives/pam-list/2008-November/msg00009.html) implies it would be possible to change the user during the authentication process, and one could presumably therefore write a PAM module which checked multiple passwords and switched the finally logged-in user appropriately. However, you'll need to do some pretty difficult development work yourself.

If your intention is to create a "hidden" user you'll need to do quite a lot more work to hide the existence of the hidden user beyond just playing with the login sequence - changing where their `$HOME` is stored, what goes in the auth log, hiding the fact that a system check would show the login sequence was modified, etc, etc.