# Meaning of files in /var/log/lightdm/ and how to properly read lightdm.log file?

Tags: 13.10, log

Tracking the slowdowns in the system, I was advised to check the files in the folder `/var/log/lightdm/`. There I see 4 files as on the image. What logs are recorded in each of them?

[image]

The other question is how to properly read file `lightdm.log`? It's content looks like this

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.8.4, UID=0 PID=1155
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
...
[+4.52s] DEBUG: Session pid=1262: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+4.53s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
```

Is this file being regenerated **each time** I log into the desktop? Or data is being appended to the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/150487/221281) if you want more info on the boot/login process.

`lightdm.log` is the log file where your display manager (also called login manager) `lightdm` write its messages.

After `lightdm` started the X-server, the X's first and last messages (like a header and a footer) will go into `x-N.log`, where `N` represents the display, just like in `/var/log/Xorg.N.log` which is the log file for the other messages from X.

The `x-N-greeter.log` file is the log file where the greeter (on ubuntu it is `unity-greeter`) messages are written, `N` again represents the display number.

You should start with `lightdm.log` and read it sequentially, and you will see that is is always reported when and where newer log files are created, e.g.:

```
[+0.22s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
...
[+0.31s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
...
[+0.87s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
```

Yes, those log files are regenerated on every reboot, but the previous log is saved with the `.old` suffix.

Comment: WOW! Thanks man for a detailed reply. Now, those time intervals (+0.22, +0.31,...) are they mean that `action1` took 0.22s, `action2` took 0.31s OR it means that `action1` took 0.22s and `action2` 0.09s (0.31-0.22)? That part confused me on the first place. I am asking this because I saw some actions took like 27s so I am not sure if they lasted 27 seconds or I they lasted `lastAction-previousAction`.

Comment: @ubuntico The time is the time elapsed since the process started when that line is printed. (So it is the second one, 0.31-0.22) If you can put your log on paste.ubuntu.com and put a link to it in your question, then we can look into it.