# Sequence of files used when booting the Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, startup

How can I find out which files the Lubuntu 14.04 in fact uses during the boot - from the very start when I turn ON the power.

I'm new to this Linux world, but I think Lubuntu must have  list of configuration files it searches for - maybe finding them or not finding them.

Especially I'm interested in seeing what is going on BEFORE the logon dialog.

I'm not interested in what ??ubuntu XX.YY did way back but what Lubutu 14.04 does right now on my machine.

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/150487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the kernel boots, then it launches init, which uses the scripts in */etc/init.d/* to start up all of the system services. The final service to be started is lightdm which in turn starts xorg and then draws a login screen. [man boot-scripts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/boot.7.html). The whole startup process, from boot loader to graphical login, is complicated, and understanding it all requires understanding how initrd works, how upstart works, how the individual init scripts work, how udev works, how xorg works, etc. Each subsystem has its own configuration scripts.

Do not expect to be able to learn it all overnight - it takes years to become an expert. I would suggest you start by reading the scripts in */etc/init.d/* and playing around with starting and stopping them. Most of the configuration files are, in general, found in */etc/* - if you look in that directory, you will find many files, each with its own purpose, each installed by some software. To find out which package a particular config file came from use dpkg eg. *dpkg -S /etc/locale.alias* will tell you that file came from the *locales* package. Some of these files have their own man pages (eg. [locale.alias](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/locale.alias.5.html)), for others you will have to read the package docs or search the web.

Comment: I've investigated a little in the file "/etc/init.d/lightdm" and I can see there is a lot of messages and echo's with some explaining texts - where are these messages and echo texts shown ? - in a log file, if so what is the name of that file ?

Comment: The output of that script is not logged by default. If you run *service lightdm restart* the output is printed on the terminal. If you change the log priority the output of the scripts will be logged to /var/log/boot.log - for details see the top answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335343/upstart-logging-output-enabled