# Unable to replicate xsessions/ubuntu.desktop in Ubuntu desktop 14.04 (with xsession-errors)

Tags: lightdm, zeitgeist, gnome-session

I have been loosing quite a lot of hair over this one.
I am trying to get a second x-session behaving exactly as the default one provided by `ubuntu.desktop`. So here is what I did:

- copied ubuntu.desktop to custom.desktop
- edited custom.desktop so the name line now reads "Name=Custom" (full content pasted below)

When I log with the `ubuntu` session from lightdm login page, everything goes as expected.
But if I try to log with `custom`, I am ending up with a wallpaper only (no side bar, not top menu, no way to launch a GUI terminal).

I cannot figure out what is special about `ubuntu.desktop`, that `custom.desktop` fails to replicate ?

### custom.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Custom
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=Unity
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

### ~/.xsession-errors

When using the provided `ubuntu` session, `.xsession-errors`is almost empty.
When using my `custom`session, it fills up with warnings ans criticals, ending with those lines:

```
  (zeitgeist-datahub:2481): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  (zeitgeist-datahub:2481): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failded
```