# Ubuntu 14.04 Lightdm: Changing exec line in ubuntu.desktop breaks top menu bar after login

Tags: unity, gnome, login, lightdm

When I log in with the default /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop, everything works fine. However, if I change the "exec" command in any way, the top menu bar (where the clock is) never appears. This is the default ubuntu.desktop that works:

**/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=Unity
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

This is the one with that breaks the top menu bar. mysess.sh has executable permissions.

**/usr/share/xsessions/custom.desktop** (only changed Exec line):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=/usr/bin/mysess.sh
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=Unity
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

/usr/bin/mysess.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

I noticed a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193357/how-do-i-create-a-popup-banner-before-login-with-lightdm) which I followed for the input above. I also noticed a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597208/unable-to-replicate-xsessions-ubuntu-desktop-in-ubuntu-desktop-14-04-with-xsess), except there was no answer.

**What is it about a shell script that would break the top panel? Any recommendations on how to debug?**

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to determine the root cause, but I found a workaround that achieves the same result.

I just added the pop up banner script to /etc/profile.d/.