# X11 startup sequence how?

Tags: xorg, lightdm

In ancient times, an X11 session was somehow started with `xinit` and ran through `/etc/X11/Xsession` and its startup files. At least in 16.04, but I think even earlier, this is not true anymore, as I found by putting some file creation into `/etc/X11/Xsession` that was never called.

Is anyone able to explain the sequence of events that happens when I log into the machine from a `lightdm` greeter, maybe in particular with Xfce4 as the window manager, but possibly with others. Which processes are started, which scripts are run? A rough starting point would even suffice, since I could dig into it from there.

Comment: Maybe this post could help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150487/what-happens-under-the-covers-to-log-me-in-and-start-up-unity-or-another-graphic

Comment: Will check, but a quick check already shows that lots of things in the mentioned lightdm-session script simply don't happen, but it may be a good starting point anyway.