# Desktop stuck on software rendering (LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE set)

Tags: opengl

In my 17.04 desktop session,

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
```

is set in the environment for all processes. That's clearly a bad idea.

I suspect that this happened because I temporarily had a bad OpenGL setup, and *something* decided to fall back to software rendering. The problem is that there is no indication whatsoever how to get unstuck.

FWIW, OpenGL works just fine with hardware acceleration when removing the environment variable:

```
unset LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1; glxinfo
```

gives the expected output and so on.

Furthermore, `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` is not set when logging into the system via `ssh`.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Have you checked the usual suspects (i.e. shell configuration files, starting from `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` if you have one, back through `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`)?

Comment: @steeldriver I should have noted that the variable is **not** set when logging in via SSH, so it has to be related to the desktop login process.

Comment: Hmm... based on this previous answer [What happens under the covers to log me in and start up Unity or another Graphical User Interface?](https://askubuntu.com/a/150488/178692) it's possibly being set via the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50_check_unity_support` script. What is the result of executing `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p -f -d :0` manually?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That wasn't it, but I got lucky and at least found a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following command once and then logging in again fixed the issue:

```
systemctl --user unset-environment LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE
```

Unfortunately, I still don't know what caused the setting in the first place.