# XPS 9370 Upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 not recognizing intel HD card

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, intel-graphics, xps

I did an upgrade via terminal yesterday, everything seemed to work fine but then I noticed very heavy CPU usage by gnome-shell. The problem is that the UHD card is not fully recognized, so it uses instead llvmpipe, so no native 3D acceleration :-(  This was working great in 17.10

Some outputs which might be useful:

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 620 [1028:07e6]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

glxinfo  | grep llv
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
```

Pls let me know if providing more info would help.  I am not sure if the driver is missing or if XORG is broken, please help.  I am using XORG at the moment, Wayland freezes (it was working in 17.10).

Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/908381/desktop-stuck-on-software-rendering-libgl-always-software-set?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
Basically, type systemctl --user unset-environment LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE and reboot, then glxinfo and system settings report the correct UHD renderer is being used ;-)  The problem seems to be that at somepoint gui crashed and then the system set this variable to avoid using native 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped setting `i915.alpha_support=1`. Try using instuction below:

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (you may use whatever editor instead of `nano`)
2. Add `i915.alpha_support=1` to the existing line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` after `quiet splash`.
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot

P.S. My backgound with this problem:

Initially I had a blackscreen after splash, so I had to add `nomodeset` (afterwards replaced to `i915.modeset=0`). Doing this I could boot the desktop, but it was rendered by LLVMpipe (software rendering using CPU capabilities).